# Google Maps API Error List

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking for a list of common errors that can be returned by the Google Maps API, such as "ZERO_RESULTS" and "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" etc.  So that I can build in some custom error handling, however am having zero luck in finding such a list.  I've tried searching through the API as well as doing a Google search and have yet to find what I'm looking for.

Does such a list exist anywhere?

Comment: It exists. See [Google Maps Javascript API V3 Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) and check classes which ends with word `Status`.